# Primefaces dialog wrong position on resize

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Test it with [primefaces demo page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkBasic.jsf), just scroll bottom our window, then press **view**
, it will show a dialog on middle center window, but try resize it, dialog position will float to top.

please show me how to fix it :(.

Sorry about my English skill;

Comment: The primefaces dialogs generally are far from perfect and have many bugs. Maybe that question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912397/primefaces-with-big-dialogs-how-to-do-this-correct? I was forced to position the dialogs myself.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t sure what you want but if you want change first position you can do it different ways:

By default dialog is positioned at center of the viewport and position option is used to change the location of the dialog. Possible values are;
• Single string value like ‘center’, ‘left’, ‘right’, ‘top’, ‘bottom’ representing the position within viewport.
• Comma separated x and y coordinate values like 200, 500
• Comma separated position values like ‘top’,‘right’. (Use single quotes when using a combination)

This you must write in your configuration map that you send:

```
Map<String,Object> configurationMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();  
configurationMap.put("position", "top");  
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("nameDialog", configurationMap, null);
```

Comment: Not working in PF 6.0. Wish there was a way to access the dialog object...